# React App: Jest encountered an error after upgrading to ViteJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, vite, ts-jest

I'm trying to use JEST after recently upgrading my app from a create-react-app to ViteJS. Previously, it had been working but after this upgrade, something appears to have been broken. Whenever I try to run one of my old tests, I get this error:

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){.App {
                                                                                      ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

      1 | import React from 'react';
    > 2 | import './App.css';
        | ^
      3 | import Home from "./Homepage/Home";
      4 | import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
      5 | import Tips from "./TipsPage/Tips";

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1495:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.tsx:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.tsx:3:1)
```

I have also previously modified package.JSON to accomodate my typescript:

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    }
  },
```

I expected that these modifications would be enough to continue working with ts-jest. My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "online-calculator",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.2.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "directories": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite --port 3000",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "vite": "^4.3.9",
    "vite-plugin-svgr": "^3.2.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

The original and unchanged test is:

```
describe('Single Page Application Test', () => {
  it('should be a Single Page Application', () => {
    render(
      <App />
    );

    // Check if the Home component is rendered initially
    expect(screen.getByText("Offensive Manuevers")).toBeInTheDocument();

    // Simulate navigating to the Tips page
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Tips'));
    expect(screen.getByText('Tips Page Works')).toBeInTheDocument();

    // Simulate navigating to the Contact page
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Contact'));
    expect(screen.getByText('Contact Page Works')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://medium.com/@dimi_2011/setting-up-css-modules-in-typescript-project-52596526d19